# NPM fails to install packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I asked this question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/981771/npm-fails-to-install-packages but it hasn't received any attention.  I think maybe this is a better forum to ask.  if it isn't, I apologise

---

working on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and NPM 6.11.3 when I issue an install from within a project I get the error below.  I've tried various packages but none succeed.  I've also googled hoping the DELETE in the path would be significant but don't find anything

```
ekkis@ubuntu:~/Mac/dev/X$ npm i eslint --save-dev
npm WARN @ekkis/X@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path /home/ekkis/Mac/dev/X/node_modules/.chalk.DELETE/node_modules/supports-color
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2 
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/ekkis/Mac/dev/X/node_modules/.chalk.DELETE/node_modules/supports-color' -> '/home/ekkis/Mac/dev/X/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/supports-color'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ekkis/.npm/_logs/2019-09-04T01_23_04_972Z-debug.log
```

the instructions ask me to rename a file but the file doesn't exist... how can I troubleshoot this?  I've looked in the logs but there's nothing useful there

Comment: Does removing your `node_modules` and `package.lock.json` first, and re-run `npm install` again solves the problem?

Comment: I *think* I've seen this sort of error when there are multiple versions of the same package in the dependency tree, possibly getting deduped, but I can't say for sure. I assume you've tried removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`?

Comment: Can you give provide your `package.json` file contain .

Comment: yes, I've removed the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` but the install won't succeed.  the `package.json` contains 2 devDependencies: ` "eslint": "^6.3.0", "mocha": "^6.2.0"` and the package builds fine under OSX but not on Ubuntu

Comment: though for whatever reason the error has change to something else but similar: "npm ERR! path /home/ekkis/dev/X/node_modules/.string-width.DELETE/node_modules/strip-ansi"

Comment: I've completely uninstalled npm, node and n and reinstalled from the n repository but the problem persists.  it seem that *either* mocha or eslint will cause the problem